# "Stars and Bars" method when all variables are multiple of same number

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Find the number of non negative integral solutions of the equation **$x + y + z + u = 100$**, where $x, y, z$ and $u$ are multiple of $5.$

My approach using stars and bars:

Since all are multiples of $5,$ if have to find the values of $p,q,r$ and $s$ in:

$5p + 5q + 5r + 5s = 100$

Or, $p + q + r + s = 20$

Now, since they are multiples of $5$, each should have a minimum of $5 (x,y,z,u)$ or $1(p,q,r,s):$

$p + q + r + s = 16$

Applying stars and bars, answer should be $19C3 = 969$

What is wrong with my approach?

Comment: You are just solving $p+q+r+s=20$. No conditions on these variables, except they are $\ge 0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas you mean the answer should be 23C3? Also, if they are multiple of 5, can zero be said a multipe of 5?

Comment: of course: $0=5\times 0$

Comment: Ok, actually the answer I have with me is 24C4 - Source answer must be wrong then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you pointed out, the number of solutions of the original equation, with the multiples of $5$ constraint, is the number of non-negative solutions of $p+q+r+s=20$. This is $\binom{20+3}{3}$.

**Remark:** Note that $0$ is a multiple of $5$, for $0=(5)(0)$.

Comment: Thanks buddy, can zero be counted as a multiple of 5?

Comment: You are welcome. I added a remark to that effect already, since it looked like the source of the slip.

Comment: thanks buddy - by the way I have the correct answer as 24C4 - this must be wrong then?

Comment: @MohitSingh There's nothing [André Nicolas](http://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) cannot solve

Comment: @DigitalBrain Haha, for sure man his reputation says it all... However, sometimes even Messi makes mistakes! :)

Comment: @MohitSingh one can't compare math to football :p

Comment: @MohitSingh Messi is not [André Nicolas](http://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all)

Comment: @DigitalBrain Hahaha, taken with respect! :)

Comment: @MohitSingh: The answer $\binom{24}{4}$ that you quote would be the right one for $x+y+z+u+v=100$, all multiples of $5$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas okay, got that buddy, thanks for your time :)